# Generate dependencies between auto-generated files

Tags: c++, cmake, code-generation

#### Description

I have a code generator that takes an XML input file and outputs a c++ header and source file. These auto-generated files are then compiled with static source files to produce a library. Simplified cmake file.

```
add_library(subdirectory/${MODULE_NAME} ${STATIC_SOURCES})

# Invoke auto-coder
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GEN_HEADER} ${GEN_SOURCE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_autocoder ${SOURCE_XML}
    DEPENDS ${SOURCE_XML}
)

# Add auto-generated source dependencies
target_sources(${MODULE_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${GEN_HEADER}
    PRIVATE ${GEN_SOURCE}
)
```

#### Problem

A generated header file `${GEN_HEADER_A}` includes other generated headers files e.g. `${GEN_HEADER_B}`. When running `make` at the top level everything builds correctly. However when building the library in isolation, it errors because `${GEN_HEADER_B}` does not exist.

#### Question

How do I add all dependencies like `${GEN_HEADER_A}` on `${GEN_HEADER_B}` without manually specifying each dependency?

#### Attempts

The `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` feature of `add_custom_command` seems to have the functionality I want. However, my attempts at using it have not resulted in the code generator being invoked for `${GEN_HEADER_B}`. My assumption is this is because I already have a rule to build `${MODULE_NAME}` when I added the library `add_library(subdirectory/${MODULE_NAME} ${STATIC_SOURCES})`

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${MODULE_NAME}
    COMMAND ...
    IMPLICIT_DEPENDS ${GEN_HEADER}
)
```

I do see `${GEN_HEADER_B}` in the `CXX.includecache` under `${GEN_HEADER_A}`

Comment: `add_custom_target` instead of `add_custom_command`. The custom targets can depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want file `A` to be (re)created when file `B` is built, you should specify this dependency **explicitely**.

Dependencies discovered by *scanning* (either automatic in `add_library`/`add_executable` commands, or via *IMPLICIT_DEPENDS* option of `add_custom_command`) are only *checked* for modification. CMake doesn't attempt to (re)create dependencies discovered by scanning.